# Format function does not work well for BCC32C

Tags: c++builder

Another difference between BCC32 and BCC32C. Format function does not show correctly for BCC32C.
In  the following example, BCC32 shows "7 test test 7" (correct), but BCC32C shows "7 test test".
I am using Rad Studio 10.1. You can replicate it creating a empty project, add a button and then the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int i=7;

    String str="test";

    ShowMessage(Format("%d %s %s %d", ARRAYOFCONST((i, str, str, i))));
}
```

Is there a workaround for this?  I am starting to think that BCC32C is not ready for production. I am finding a lot of problems.

Comment: `Format()` is fine, but `ARRAYOFCONST` seems to mess up things. See answer by @Sam. His solution works. `ARRAYOFCONST` should produce the same set of two arguments. And indeed, **yet another problem with BCC32C**. This works fine in the 64-bit (also Clang) compiler.

Comment: Is the `OPENARRAY()` macro also affected? I imagine it would be, since it is declared similarly to `ARRAYOFCONST()`, just that it uses a user-defined typename instead of `TVarRec`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way is to do this:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int i=7;
    String str="test";
    TVarRec Args[] = {i, str, str, i};

    ShowMessage(Format("%d %s %s %d", Args, 3));
}
```

Sam

Comment: `ARRAYOFCONST(())` should work too and produce the same set of arguments (array and number). It does in BCC32 (Borland) and BCC64 (Clang), but not in BCC32C (Clang). But your code works in BCC32C too, so it is a good workaround for the defective `ARRAYOFCONST(())`.

Comment: But, does anyone know *why* `ARRAYOFCONST` is defective?  What it is doing differently in BCC32C that it is not doing in BCC32 and BCC64? I don't have Berlin installed, or I would look for myself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am not sure why `ARRAYOFCONST` does not work. It might have something to do with the way pre-processor expands the macro. I believe it should be reported as bug to Embarcadero. Having said that, I have had horrible experiences with macros. And as a personal practice (**NOT recommending it to everyone, Just myself**), I avoid using them as much as possible.

Comment: Already reported, see [RSP-14062](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14062), [RSP-15811](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15811), and [RSP-15588](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15588).  Bruneau Babet [posted a patch](https://etsfftp01.embarcadero.com/?u=r3d3&p=8Yng&path=/clang32.zip) until an official fix is released.

Answer (score 1):

After researching, it seems I need to wait for a new release of Rad Studio.
Meanwhile, I have created a workaround that for now it seems to work:

```
#if defined(__clang__)
    #define VRARRAY(...) (TVarRec[]){__VA_ARGS__}, sizeof((TVarRec[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(TVarRec)
#else
    #define VRARRAY(...) System::OpenArray<System::TVarRec>(__VA_ARGS__), sizeof(System::OpenArrayCounter<System::TVarRec>::Count (__VA_ARGS__))-1
#endif
```

Then, I can use:

```
ShowMessage(Format("%d %s %s %d", VRARRAY(i, str, str, i)));
```

Comment: You could also use `ShowMessage(System::String().sprintf(L"%d %s %s %d", i, str, str, i));`

Comment: I use `String::sprintf()` as well (and `cat_sprintf()`).  I never did like `Format()`, it is too ugly in C++, and not as flexible as `sprint()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with you %100. With very few exception I use `String::sprintf()` in my code all the time. The only thing that bothers me about it is `sprintf` is not **static** an I think it should be. Do you agree?

Comment: @Sam: Usually, I use it in a manner that would be better suited as a static, yes.  But not always.  Sometimes I do declare a `String` variable and then later call `sprintf()` on it after determining which parameters to pass. I suppose a static could still be used in that situation, though it would involve an additional assignment.